# What is Sitecore Datasource and why should use?

Tags: sitecore, datasource

I'm new to Sitecore XP 8.2 and try to study by articles and youtube.

However, I can't figure out why we should use datasource, instead of having multiple items in the content tree?  How  can I enable Global on the content tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by 'datasource' means 'Rendering Datasource Location' heres a real life example, where using datasource is helpfull, instead of having data items underneath each page item.

Lets say, you have a Footer module, which you would like to include on all content pages in your website. And the Editors should be able to change the content of the footer module on all pages, but the effect should be global.

In this case, could a solution be, to make a folder at the top of your tree structure called 'Shared Modules', and point the 'Footer Rendering Datasource Location' at this folder.
In case an editor changes the footer text on the main page or a subpage, the effect will allways be saved in the same location.

unlike, a 'Texbox module' which you would like to have multiple of on multiple pages. these would you like to have placed underneath each of your content pages in a folder e.g 'Page Modules'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sitecore Datasource for a variety of reasons. One of the reasons is to use this instead of context item so that you can refer to another item in Sitecore content tree. Another good reason is to personalize your content or run the A/B testing, content testing. Using Sitecore datasource, make different parts of page componentize and all this helps content editor to improve experience in content editor.

For some good information on using Sitecore datasource, you can look at

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-improve-experience-editor-sitecore-number-ways-rohit-chopra
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-personalize-content-conditional-renderings-sub-rohit-chopra

Answer (score 0):

In short, with datasources you can re-use your items, makes your life much easier if you want to go with personalization and its easier to manage in terms of security/workflows.

Answer (score 0):

A datasource is a pointer from your presentation to a content item. This item can easily be picked from a global or local placement in the content tree. You can still navigate from the datasource to other items (like subitems) if you want a more complex structure for your content.

The advantages of using datasources, is that Sitecores presentation engine, Experience Editor and marketing/personalization is based on the usage of datasources. Further you cater for reuse of content, as multiple presentations can point to the same datasource item.

By using datasources you decouple the content from the structure of your content tree and hierarchy.